# reading string from file segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, string, constructor, stream

```
class BPP
{
    unsigned            n;                  /* nº de instancias */
    vector<string>      nombre_instancia;   /* nombre de la instancia*/
```

In the constructor, I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) when:

```
file1.open(fich1);
    if (file1.is_open()){
        file1 >> (unsigned &) n;
        for (unsigned k = 0 ; k < n ; ++k){
            getline(file1, nombre_instancia[k]); #gives the segmentation fault
```

The 2 first lines in fich1 are:

```
10
 P_0
```

Comment: I'd rewrite `file1 >> (unsigned &) n;` as `file1 >> n;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you have not resized nombre_instancia beyond its original size of 0. Try this instead:

```
  file1 >>  n;
  nombre_instancia.resize(n);     
    for (unsigned k = 0 ; k < n ; ++k){
        getline(file1, nombre_instancia[k]); #gives the segmentation fault
```

Comment: I've do it before. Sorry for not complete information `nombre_instancia.resize(n, "");`

Answer (score 2):

You need to populate the vector with elements *before* accessing them via [`vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). In the following code the vector is empty:

```
for (unsigned k = 0 ; k < n ; ++k){
    getline(file1, nombre_instancia[k]);
```

so the call to `nombre_instancia[k]` is out of bounds. You can use [`vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to create the elements:

```
if (file >> n) // Ensure 'n' correctly assigned.
{
    nombre_instancia.resize(n);
    for (unsigned k = 0 ; k < n ; ++k){
        getline(file1, nombre_instancia[k]);
}
```

An alternative is to use [`vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) without knowing up front what the number of elements will be.

Comment: when I did resize after reading the n variable, I get a value of 0 when doint std::cout, or ""(in strings). Why?? Have to use push_back by force??

Comment: @freinn, do you mean `n` is 0? If so, it means the value read from the file was not a valid `unsigned int` (if `n` was initialised to 0) or was 0.

Comment: no, I mean that 0 is the value that std::cout show to me in console, and the reading from file doesn't work properly

Comment: what call to `std::cout`!? I don't know what variable has a value of 0.

Comment: my program doesn't read the file properly and all variables keep void (0 or "") please talk to me in chat!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reserve space in a vector if you want to use getline. By giving nombre_instancia[k], the program has an uninitialised vector. Use reserve, or push_back(null)